# UIControlStateHighlighted equivalent for UISegmentedControl, iphone

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

If one is  using UIbuttons, Uibuttons background image/colour can be set with property UIControlStateHighlighted.

```
[UIButton setBackgroundImage: UIImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

I want similar property for UIsegmentedControl. If any of these segmented bar is pressed I want to change colour of that bar only when it is pressed. Colour should get back to default when that bar is released. May be I am missing something obvious  but is there any property of UIsegmentedControl ?.

thanks for any help in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i was trying to do same thing and this is not possible, i tried all the way, so i created two buttons with image and put together(so feel like segmented button).

Answer (score 0):

```
    [segmentControl setMomentary:YES];
```

Comment: But I want to set custom colour for each segment. setting momentary property changes tintcolor momentarily but it chooses it's own colour (dark shade of default tintcolor).

Comment: Use a UIButton then. No other go if you wish to customize

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) only has tintColor which applies to the whole control.